# Why is it impossible to change constructor function from prototype?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I have such example.

```
function Rabbit() {
    var jumps = "yes";
};
var rabbit = new Rabbit();
alert(rabbit.jumps);                    // undefined
alert(Rabbit.prototype.constructor);    // outputs exactly the code of the function Rabbit();
```

I want to change the code in `Rabbit()` so that the `var jumps` becomes public. I do it this way:

```
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = function Rabbit() {
    this.jumps = "no";
};
alert(Rabbit.prototype.constructor);    // again outputs the code of function Rabbit() and with new this.jumps = "no";
var rabbit2 = new Rabbit();             // create new object with new constructor
alert(rabbit2.jumps);                   // but still outputs undefined
```

Why is it not possible to change the code in constructor function this way?

Comment: Your second code says a Rabbit doesn't jump, which evaluates to false, hence the error - try `this.jumps = "yes"`

Comment: @wheresrhys All non-empty strings (i.e. strings with length greater than zero) evaluate to true in JavaScript; even `"false"`, more so, then, `"no"` :)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You cannot change a constructor by reassigning to `prototype.constructor`

What is happening is that `Rabbit.prototype.constructor` is a  pointer to the original constructor (`function Rabbit(){...}`), so that users of the 'class' can detect the constructor from an instance. Therefore, when you try to do:

```
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = function Rabbit() {
    this.jumps = "no";
};
```

You're only going to affect code that relies on `prototype.constructor` to dynamically instantiate objects from instances.

When you call `new X`, the JS engine doesn't reference `X.prototype.constructor`, it uses the `X` as the constructor function and `X.prototype` as the newly created object's prototype., ignoring `X.prototype.constructor`.

A good way to explain this is to implement the `new` operator ourselves. ( Crockford will be happy, no more new ;)

```js
// `new` emulator
// 
// Doesn't reference `.constructor` to show that prototype.constructor is not used
// when istantiating objects a la `new`
function make(ctorFun, argsArray) {
  // New instance attached to the prototype but the constructor
  // hasn't been called on it.
  const newInstance = Object.create(ctorFun.prototype);
  ctorFun.apply(newInstance, argsArray);
  return newInstance;
}

// If you create a utility function to create from instance, then it uses the
// inherited `constructor` property and your change would affect that.
function makeFromInstance(instance, argsArray) {
  return make(instance.constructor, argsArray);
}

function X(jumps) {
  this.jumps = jumps;
}

// Flip the constructor, see what it affects
X.prototype.constructor = function(jumps) {
  this.jumps = !jumps;
}

const xFromConstructorIsGood = make(X, [true]);
const xFromInstanceIsBad = makeFromInstance(xFromConstructorIsGood, [true]);

console.log({
  xFromConstructorIsGood,
  xFromInstanceIsBad
});
```

**Inheritance in JS**

Libraries that help with JS inheritance implement inheritance and do rely on `prototype.constructor` with something in the spirit the following:

```
function extend(base, sub) {

  function surrogateCtor() {}
  // Copy the prototype from the base to setup inheritance
  surrogateCtor.prototype = base.prototype;
  sub.prototype = new surrogateCtor();
  // The constructor property is set to the base constructor
  // with the above trick, let's fix it
  sub.prototype.constructor = sub;
}
```

You can see that in the above code, we have to *fix* the constructor property because it's sometimes used to create instantiate an object when you only have an instance. but it doesn't affect the actual constructor. See my post about JS inheritance http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html

**How to redefine a constructor**
If you really want to redefine a constructor, just do

```
// If Rabbit had any custom properties on it 
// (or static properties as some call it), they would not be copied, you'd have to do that manually using getOwnPropertyNames

// See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames
var oldProto = Rabbit.prototype;
Rabbit = function() {...};
Rabbit.prototype = oldProto;
// Don't keep the old constructor
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit;
```

Note that this would not affect code that had already copied that reference, for example:

```
const myRefRabbit = Rabbit
```

Comment: Yes, `prototype.constructor` doesn't affect anything, really.

Comment: Except this won't copy static functions right?  Static functions show up under `Rabbit` not under `Rabbit.prototype` when you inspect the class.

Comment: @mattclimbs true, but OP wasn't using any in his example

Comment: @katspaugh Sorry about the late reply. It does affect code that relies on `prototype.constructor` to detect the constructor from an instance as explained in the "Inheritance in JS" section. I know what you mean though, it doesn't affect anything in the core language.

Comment: What can we do when we don't have a reference to `Rabbit`? E.g. I have `this` which references an instance of `Rabbit`, but I don't have the reference to the `Rabbit` type. Can we still redefine `constructor` so that it works even when calling `new Rabbit()`? Thank you.

Comment: @tonix No, you can't. There's no way you can change someone else's reference to `Rabbit` that has already been retrieved.

Comment: OK. So I guess the only option to e.g. intercept the access (`get/set`) of a static property given a `constructor function` which the client code already references would be to redefine that property's descriptor using an `accessor descriptor` (provided that the property is `configurable`), right? Thank you!

Comment: @tonix Very likely, you should try it first and then ask a separate question since you don't really care about changing the constructor.

Comment: @JuanMendes Well, if I could change `Rabbit = class extends Rabbit {...}` when I get a reference to `Rabbit` from a `target` variable in my code (passed from the client code), then I can and would override create a getter/setter property for the property I want to intercept, and again I will define a property with an accessor descriptor... So yeah, I guess that's the only possible way, provided that we can't say `target = class extends target {...}` in a way that it modifies `Rabbit` as well...

Comment: @tonix I'm not sure why you're explaining this to me. I obviously know this but I've given you a simpler solution: `Rabbit.someProp = blah` should work for all users of Rabbit. You could use accessor descriptors for more flexibility

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes, I basically need to perform some additional operations before e.g. the value of `Rabbit.someProp` gets retrieved and returned to the consumer, or maybe return a completely different value when the consumer writes `var consumerVariable = Rabbit.someProp // This could be "blah", but not guaranteed`. It's for an AOP library I'm writing in JS. An accessor descriptor can give me this flexibility. Thank you for pointing out that there's no other way to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do `Rabbit.prototype = {...oldProto, ...Rabbit.prototype}` instead of `Rabbit.prototype = oldProto` as you lose the Rabbit.prototype.constructor property with the latter way? (referring to the second to last code snippet)

Comment: @EricXu Good call, since the constructor would still point to the initial constructor. However, I would prefer just doing `Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit` since it's easier to understand what is happening.

Comment: @RuanMendes That's a nice explicit way of doing it. :D

Answer (score 0):

**This is wonderful workaround creating an object from a literal, not from constructor function.**

Firstly, if you want `jumps` member to be contained in the object, rather than being just a local variable in the constructor then you need `this` keyword.

```
function Rabbit() {
    this.jumps = "yes";
};

var rabbit = new Rabbit();
alert(rabbit.jumps);                    // not undefined anymore
```

And now you can easily now access `jumps` publicly the way you wanted:

```
rabbit.jumps = 'no';
alert(rabbit.jumps);                    // outputs 'no'
```

But still if you create another Rabbit object it will initially have 'yes' as defined in the constructor, right?

```
var rabbit2 = new Rabbit();
alert(rabbit.jumps);                     // outputs 'no' from before
alert(rabbit2.jumps);                    // outputs 'yes'
```

What you could do is creating a Rabbit from some default Rabbit Object. The concrete rabbits will always have the default value from default Rabbit object even when you change it on the fly unless you have changed the value in concrete rabbit object (implementation). This is a different than @Juan Mendes's solution which is probably the best but it can open another point of view.

```
Rabbit = {jumps : 'yes'};    // default object

rabbit = Object.create(Rabbit);
Rabbit.jumps = 'no';
rabbit2 = Object.create(Rabbit);

console.log(rabbit.jumps);   // outputs "no" - from default object
console.log(rabbit2.jumps);  // outputs "no" - from default object

// but...
rabbit.jumps = 'yes';
Rabbit.jumps = 'unknown';

console.log(rabbit.jumps);   // outputs "yes" - from concrete object
console.log(rabbit2.jumps);  // outputs "unknown" - from default object
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
function Rabbit() {
  this.jumps = "no";
};

var rabbit = new Rabbit();
alert(rabbit.jumps);  // Prints "no"
```

Comment: I'll give this answer a `+1` if you explain why setting `jumps` in the prototype does not work.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I know that I can change the original function. But I want to know is it possible to change it another way, from prototype.