# Access constructor properties outside the constructor

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this constructor:

```
function Person() {
  this.name = 'jviotti';
}
```

How can I access the value of `this.name` from outside the constructor, to set it to another value for example?

```
Person.name
// Person

Person.constructor.name
// Function
```

Comment: Why? What would be the purpose of this?

Comment: Customizing a constructor from a third party library before instanciating it

Comment: You can't. It's not a property, it's just a line of Javascript code. If you wanted your class to have configurable defaults, you should have put them in an accessible object, not hard-coded them.

Comment: Take a look, for example, at how `jQuery.ajaxSetup()` configures the defaults to `jQuery.ajax()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override properties by inheriting from the object "subclassing" it:

```
var inherits = function(childCtor, parentCtor) {
  function tempCtor() {};
  tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
  childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
};
function Person() {
  this.name = 'jviotti';
}
Person.prototype.getName=function(){
  return this.name;
}
function myPerson(){
  Person.call(this);
  // overriding default value for name
  this.name="my person's name";
}
inherits(myPerson,Person);
// override getName and calling it's parent
myPerson.prototype.getName=function(){
  return "From myPerson:" + myPerson.superClass_
    .getName.call(this);
}
var p = new myPerson();
console.log(p.getName());//From myPerson:my person's name
```

Not sure if this is what you wanted to do. In your example the property `name` is an instance property. So you can change it's default value by "subclassing" Person. Prototype properties and methods are shared by all instances and can be used for default values and methods of the object.

The code shows how to change these properties by defining a `myPerson` that behaves like a Person but overrides setting a default value for `name` and adds implementation `getName`

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an instance of that object.

```
function Person() {
  this.name = 'jviotti';
}

var person1 = new Person();
console.log(person1.name); // jviotti

person1.name = 'ctcherry';
console.log(person1.name); // ctcherry
```

Comment: Yeah, but what if I want to edit the constructor properties before instanciating it?

Comment: You can't edit the constructor where it sits. But you could subclass from it, see this answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267157/why-is-it-impossible-to-change-constructor-function-from-prototype

Answer (score 1):

In **es6**, If you are using class then create an instance of class and instance.property, you will get an answer

```
class Example {
  constructor(size) {
    this.size = size;
  }
}

$ var example = new Example(5);
$ example.size; // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to call it. If you're using prototype, then:

```
function Person(){
  this.name="John"
}

function Person(){} //re-defining the constructor
Person.prototype.name = "Jane"; //changing the constructor
var person = new Person();
console.log("person.name") //"Jane"
```