# modifying or inheriting from constructor function possible?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I would like to add additional properties to some objects, such as `window.URL.params:{}`, 
I am assuming this cannot be done with the window.URL object as the constructor will have to be modified. so i created a new object window.NEWURL

### code as it stands

```
function NEWURL(url)
{
    urlObj = new URL(url);
    for (prop in urlObj)
    {
        if(urlObj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        {
            this[prop] = urlObj[prop];
        }
    };
    var request = {};
    var pairs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++)
    {
        var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
        request[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
    this.params = request;
}
```

1. is it possible to modify the window.URL constructor? [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267157/why-is-it-impossible-to-change-constructor-function-from-prototype) shows you can modify a constructor but I don't think this would work for a window object(Well i think that's what it shows).
2. is it possible to inherit from the window.URL object rather than just looping through the properties?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you probably could overwrite `window.URL`. However, a custom is usually better than [extending the native ones](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to modifying the existing object (it's also good practice to not mutate objects you don't own), you can extend the URL object, adding additional properties to it.

Whenever you want this object you should call your function to fetch it rather than calling window.url directly.

This is the approach that jQuery uses for the dom (basically wrapping the dom objects instead of mutating).

Simplest way to do it inherit:

```
function myUrl() {
    var url = Object.create(new URL());
    // now mutate url however you want.
    url.foo = "c00l";
    return url;
}

// Another approach

function MyURL() {
   URL.call(this);
   // Do what you want.
   this.foo = "c00l";
}

MyURL.prototype = Object.create(URL.prototype);
```