# Javascript how to override a constructor method?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a `View` class that has a constructor method `initialize` I think this is a constructor method, correct me if wrong.

```
var View = function(obj) {
    this.initalize = obj.initalize;
};
```

What I would like to achieve is something gets called when the Class is instantiated.

How can I pass in an object like so?

```
var chatView = new View({
    initialize: function() {
        alert('Yay for initialization');
    }
});
```

So that when I instantiate the `View` I can pass an object to the constructor and within a key `initialize` which value is a function and this key specifically gets called when instantiated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it impossible to change constructor function from prototype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267157/why-is-it-impossible-to-change-constructor-function-from-prototype)

Comment: *What I would like to achieve is something gets called when the Class is instantiated.* Then call it.

Comment: Ideally I can just pass an object, similar to Backbone.js https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js I know they use `_.extend()` but the idea is when you instantiate a `View` it does it on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I get it right, there is a simple way of achieving what you want:

```
var View = function(obj) {
    obj.initialize();
}
```

This way, the initialize function gets called whenever you instantiate a View class.

Be aware that if you want to do real "initialization code" inside the initialize function to work, you could use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) (or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)):

```
var View = function(obj) {
    if (typeof obj.initialize === 'function') {
        obj.initialize.call(this);
    }
}

var chatView = new View({
    initialize: function() {
        this.property = 'property';
    }
});

console.log(chatView.property); // outputs property
```

Comment: Seems legit, let me give it a shot. I noticed backbone.js does something similar with the `call()`. I will need to investigate what it does further.

Comment: Sweet man thanks. Should I be aware of anything using this? Any particular reason why `_.extend()` would give me any benefit over doing this?

Comment: I am not an user of the _ library, but I would say that if you really want to use this "custom initialization" concept, you could check the availability of the `initialize` method inside `obj` before calling it to make the `View` class more robust (I will make an edit).

Comment: Very good, I knew I needed to implement some validation, this is just icing on the cake.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have a constructor, remember that javascript is based on prototype. This is an example of "constructor" you can create

```
function Example (firstname, lastname) {
this.firstname = firstname;
this.lastname = lastname;
}

Example.prototype.getFullname = function () {
return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
}
```

If you want to create a constructor function you must to call it after you instantiate the function.

But this is a better structure you can use. I recommended only if you need a constructor function and private function. Otherwise, use a simple structure with methods declared with prototype, you can get a better performance.

```
var MyObject = (function () {

    // Constructor
    function MyObject (foo) {
        this._foo = foo;
    }

    function privateFun (prefix) {
        return prefix + this._foo;
    }

    MyObject.prototype.publicFun = function () {
        return privateFun.call(this, '>>');
    }

    return MyObject;
})();


var myObject = new MyObject('bar');
```

With this code you have a constructor, but it's a "private" function, so you can't overwrite it after instantiate the object.

Here I have a link I create testing differents structures:
https://plnkr.co/edit/qzgWVZlnIFnWl0MoUe5n?p=preview

**The result:**

Test 1: ~15k (with private function) - Recommended ONLY if you want/need a private function

Test 2: ~38k (with private function) - Not recommended, it's returning an object which is really bad.

Test 3: ~8k (without private function) - Recommended, it has the best performance, but you can't create a private function, which means, anybody can call any function :S