# Unable to Override methods on Promise class - Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, postman, es6-promise

I am trying to override `then`, `catch` and `finally` functions. This is to create a global counter and monitor the pending promises.

The code needs to be executed Postman Sandbox, so I cannot use any NPM modules. I needs to do this with Native JS

Below is the code that I am trying to work out

```
_constructor = Promise.prototype.constructor
_then = Promise.prototype.then

Promise.prototype.constructor = (...args) => {
    console.log("Promise constructor called")
    let data = _constructor(...args)
    console.log("Promise constructor finished")
    return data;
}

Promise.prototype.then = (...args) => {
    console.log("then called")
    let data = _then.call(this, args)
    console.log("then finished")
    return data;
}

function test2(num) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (num > 1) {
            setTimeout(()=> {
                resolve(num)
            }, 10)
        } else {
            reject(num);
        }
    });
    return promise
}

test2(10).then((num) => {
    console.log("Inside then")
    setTimeout(() => console.log("Promise has been resolved - " + num), 20);
})
```

But when I run this I get below error

```
    let data = _then.call(this, args)
                     ^

TypeError: Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver #<Object>
    at Object.then (<anonymous>)
    at Promise.then.args (/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/test/postman/temp.jsx:15:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tarun.lalwani/test/postman/temp.jsx:33:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
```

I am not sure what is wrong here, or is this the right way to do it or not.

Comment: this code is problematic , if you override "then" and call it inside your "then" then you wont be able to do  await on the  _then.call(this, args) as you will run an infinite recursive call. that means you cant get track of the pending promises as you function is sync without the ability to wait the async call. what you need to do is create a new function like "myThen" that warps then and not override it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many problems with this:

- `new Promise` will invoke `Promise`, not the overridden `Promise.prototype.constructor`.
- Arrow functions are no constructors. They will throw when being called with `new`.
- Calling `_constructor` (i.e. the builtin `Promise`) without `new` will throw
- Arrow functions are no methods. They have a lexical `this` value, not a dynamic receiver.
- You want to `apply` the `args`, not `call` them, or use spread syntax

You can solve these by using `function`s and the `Reflect` object properly, however I guess it's much simpler to use ES6 subclassing for this:

```
Promise = class extends Promise {
    constructor(...args) {
        console.log("Promise constructor called")
        let data = super(...args)
        console.log("Promise constructor finished")
        return data;
    }
    then(...args) {
        console.log("then called")
        let data = super.then(...args)
        console.log("then finished")
        return data;
    }
};
```

Of course, nothing here actually determines when a promise is pending or not.

Comment: You are right, it has a issue with recursion with previous answer. I didn't use any of the solutions as it ended up being a [bug](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4131) in Postman

Answer (score 2):

> In arrow functions, this retains the value of the enclosing lexical
>   context's this. In global code, it will be set to the global object

[`this` in different contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

You need to change

```
Promise.prototype.constructor = (...args) => {
    console.log("Promise constructor called")
    let data = _constructor(...args)
    console.log("Promise constructor finished")
    return data;
}

Promise.prototype.then = (...args) => {
    console.log("then called")
    let data = _then.call(this, args)
    console.log("then finished")
    return data;
}
```

into

```
Promise.prototype.constructor = function (...args) {
    console.log("Promise constructor called")
    let data = _constructor(...args)
    console.log("Promise constructor finished")
    return data;
}

Promise.prototype.then = function (...args) {
    console.log("then called")
    let data = _then.call(this, args)
    console.log("then finished")
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks the `then` function now works but the `console.log("Promise constructor called")` still doesn't get logged. I have used `new Promise(...)`. Something I am missing on that part?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267157/why-is-it-impossible-to-change-constructor-function-from-prototype

Comment: Was reading that only and was about to post that link here :-). Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

@Tarun Lalwani, You cannot override promise constructor like above, as promise is a class not a function. As @Bergi mentioned, you need to use Reflect to intercept Promise constructor.

The issue here is that ES6 classes (e.g. Promise) are not callable, the way ES5 built in classes (e.g. Array). The emitted code that the compiler produces uses super.call which throws in ES6 engine.

The fix here is to use Reflect.construct if it exists instead of call. Reflect.construct is not something we can polifill, but we can assume if built-in Promise is there, Refelect.construct is there too.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15202#issuecomment-297518643

In the link above, it is been mentioned how to extend constructor. By doing so you can able to print `console.log("Promise constructor called")` when you call `new Promise()`